# Best deploy method for registry and certificates

Tags: deployment, installation, registry, certificate

I need to deploy some registry keys and install certificates in some stores on each of my clients computer.

To avoid errors and make it easy to use, I want to create an automated process to do so, but I don't what are the options.

What are the possibilities to upgrade the windows registry and install a few certificates?

- Batch files?
- Installer?
- Deployment package?

The sweetest thing would allow my clients to configure their computer by clicking a button right into one of my ASP.net page, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the following problem :

On windows XP, the utility called "certutil", that is used to deploy certificates is unavailable.
To install it, I must install on each client the Windows server 2003 Administration tools and it's cumbersome.

The best solution I've found so far is to export my certificates from the registry, and install them through my clients' registry ! I can only share a big .REG file that will do all the installation work.

Each one of my certificates must go into the following registry key :

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates]

And by exporting my registry, I can therefore share the exported .REG file to allow other users to install them!

Can I have trouble with that solution ? Is there a better way ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I looked again at the group policy preference I was using.  There is an option "Run in logged-on user's security context (user policy option)" that I enabled and now the registry entry is persisting